# how to use regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var pattern=/[A-za-z0-9]/;
if((fs.value||ls.value||ad1.value||ad2.value||pc.value||city.value||email.value)!=pattern)
{alert("fields not entered");
return false;}
else
return true;
```

Even after entering all the fields in the form, I get alert message "field not entered.  Here fs,ls,ad1,ad2,email,pc and city are form field values

Comment: You are checking whether the last non-empty value **is** a regular expression, which will never be the case. Have a you looked at any documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: This is pretty easy to google (*"javascript regexp"*), one way is to use `str.match(regexp)` in your condition.

Comment: You can't just compare a string to a regex, you have to run it through a regex tester like `ls.value.match(pattern)` et al

Comment: Best site for learn regx  https://regex101.com/

Comment: Simple solution: `var fields = [fs, ls, ...]; if (fields.every(f => pattern.test(f.value))) { ... }`.

Comment: BTW your regex only matches a single character - prob not what you want

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the values from those fields and run them thru the regex matching tool while passing the regex to that method.

```
var pattern=/[A-za-z0-9]/;
"string to check against regex pattern".match(pattern);
```

See more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)